# $watch not firing inside directive when watched variable is updated asynchronously outside the directive (from server)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck trying to watch a model from a directive I am creating. I am creating a Pagination directive, into which I'm passing total-number-of-records and current page number (which I get from a server).
Basically, I'm computing number-of-pages based on total-number-of-records and user's selection of number-of-records-per-page. The computed number is pushed to an array, and the array is bound to a drop down. 
The selected value of the drop down is bound to a model which can either be the user's selection, or it might get updated from the server based on some other interactions the user performs (such as changing the number of records per page). Below - my code.

My directive definition:

```
<paginator total-count="al.pager.totalElements" page-number="al.pager.number"></paginator>
```

My directive implementation (paginator.js):

```
scope: {
    totalCount: '=',
    pageNumber: '='
},
link: function (scope) {
    scope.pageList = [];
    getPageNumbers() {
        noOfPages = Math.ceil(scope.totalCount / scope.pageSize); // pageSize is number of records to show in each page
        scope.pageList.length = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
            scope.pageList.push(i);
        }
    }

    getPageNumbers();
}
```

My directive view (paginator.html):

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="pageNumber" ng-change="pageNumberChange()">
        <md-option ng-value="page" ng-repeat="page in pageList">{{page}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is, when the total number of records in the database change, I want the number of pages drop-down to be updated and the selected value to show the page number returned by the database.

So, in the directive I'm watching the "totalCount" variable and when it changes, I am recomputing the number of pages like so.

```
link: function (scope) {
    getPageNumbers() {
        noOfPages = Math.ceil(scope.totalCount / scope.pageSize); // pageSize is number of records to show in each page
        for (let i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
            scope.pageList.push(i);
        }
    }
    scope.$watch('totalCount', getPageNumbers(), true);
}
```

The problem is, when I get a new totalCount from server, my getPageNumbers() method is not called. Because the drop down list is not getting populated, the selected value is not getting displayed.
Can anyone see what I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One quick thing I noticed - the listener in scope.$watch should be a function, but you are passing it the result of getPageNumbers() instead of the function itself. Maybe try `scope.$watch('totalCount', getPageNumbers, true)` ?

Comment: Aaah!!! That was in fact the problem. I did not notice that I was invoking the function. Thanks a lot!! In addition, I had to define the watcher like so: scope.$watch(function() { 
                return scope.totalCount; 
            }, getPageNumbers);
Just passing it as 'totalCount' or 'scope.totalCount' did not work. I don't know what the difference is. Will be very grateful if someone can explain why...

Comment: @bags, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark this question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener (2nd argument) in `scope.$watch` should be a function, but you are passing it the result of `getPageNumbers()` instead of the function itself.

Try `scope.$watch('totalCount', getPageNumbers, true)`